# How to connect PHP search bar to MySQL database - access denied

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

As a project I am trying to create a search box that searches a database for a product and then returns an answer to the user. However I am having issues with it at the moment and seemingly can't access the database. 
I continue to get this error message on my site -

> Connection Failed: Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

The code that I am using is below:

```
$search_value=$_POST["search"];
$con=new mysqli("$localhost","$username","$password","$dbname");
if($con->connect_error){
    echo 'Connection Failed: '.$con->connect_error;
}else{
```

A few questions: 
What is the address of my database (created through MySQL wizard)is it still localhost? 
What else am I doing wrong here.

Sorry for the simple question.

Comment: Yes it should be localhost.  Check the values of all the variables you are passing.  It looks like the $password variable is empty.

Comment: Does this help? https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect

Comment: There's no need to wrap your variables in quotes... `new mysqli('localhost', $username, $password, $dbname)`. Make sure all those variables are defined and have appropriate values set

Comment: The password is not ok.

Comment: Tried all of the above, just doesn't seem to work. Password should be $ the actual password?